# Migration error Magento 1.9.3.2 to 2.1.8

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-2.1, php-5.6, data-migration

I have Migrated from Magento `ver 1.9.3.2` to Magento `ver 2.1.8` successfully using `Data Migration tool`.

In admin, catalogs and customers showing fine on grid but after clicked on it showing below error:

> (Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException): The requested
>   component ("datetime") is not found. Before using, you must add the
>   implementation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you can find the answer i followed below link you can go through this.

[Go Through This Link](https://community.magento.com/t5/Technical-Issues/The-requested-component-quot-datetime-quot-is-not-found-Before/td-p/66297)

Comment: You should avoid [link only answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info).

Answer (score 1):

***You must configure the offset to migrate timestamp fields. To transform time to a different time zone, use the Data Migration Tool’s \Migration\Handler\Timezone handler during Migration***:

Please see the details at

http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/migration/migration-migrate-follow-up.html

I guess same are need for product

Comment: This will help me . Let me try

Comment: i am getting same error after edit map-customer.xml file.

Comment: I followed this link and its working fine.   https://community.magento.com/t5/Technical-Issues/The-requested-component-quot-datetime-quot-is-not-found-Before/td-p/66297

Comment: cool.Please post here as answer